Azure Synapse SQL Dedicated Pool Stuck in Scaling Mode for over 48 hours
Question:
I have a SQL Dedicated Pool in Azure Synapse that has been stuck in the "Scaling" status since 2.5 days. This unexpected behaviour has disrupted our operations, as the data is not fully up to date and an important ADF pipeline is not triggered. This is particularly concerning as the scaling process has worked fine for the past years. We cannot restart the service as it is in read mode and all configuration is grayed out.
Steps Taken:
Checked Status: Used Azure CLI to confirm the SQL Dedicated Pool is in "Scaling" status: bash az synapse sql pool show --name  --workspace-name  --resource-group 
Tried Pausing/Resuming: Attempted to pause and resume the pool, but received the following error: (SkuAssignmentInProgress) A service objective assignment on server '' and database '' is already in progress. Please wait until the service objective assignment state for the database is marked as 'Completed'.
Checked Permissions: Verified that I have the necessary permissions (Contributor and Owner) on the resource.
Activity Logs: Searched for relevant activity logs using Azure Portal and Azure Monitor, but did not find specific events indicating the start of the scaling operation.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest any additional steps to resolve this? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

I’d start by raising a support request with Microsoft

We did immediately and it was an issue with the task which looped in the background. Only MS Support could solve it.
